# SQL Select first missing value in a series

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I was asked the following: I have a table (lets call it tbl) and it has one column of type int (let call it num) and it had sequential numbers in it:

```
num
---
 1
 2
 4
 5
 6
 8
 9
 11
```

Now you need to write a query that returns the first missing number (in this example that answer would be 3).

here's my answer (works):

```
select top 1 (num + 1)
from tbl
where (num + 1) not in (select num from tbl)
```

after writing this, I was asked, what if tbl contained 10 million records - how would you improve performence (because obviously myinner query would cause a full table scan).

My thoughts were about an index in on the num field and doing a not exists. but I would love to hear some alternatives.

Comment: Take a look at some articles on [gaps and islands](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/the-sql-of-gaps-and-islands-in-sequences/) for a different view on solving the issues as well as some performance comparisons.

Answer (score 6):

In SQL Server 2012+, I would simply use `lead()`:

```
select num
from (select num, lead(num) over (order by num) as next_num
      from tbl
     ) t
where next_num <> num + 1;
```

However, I suspect that your version would have the best performance if you have an index on `tbl(num)`.  The `not exists` version is worth testing:

```
select top 1 (num + 1)
from tbl t
where not exists (select 1 from tbl t2 where t2.num = t.num + 1);
```

The only issue is getting the *first* number.  You are not guaranteed that the table is read "in order".  So, this will return one number.  With an index (or better yet, clustered index) on `num`, the following should be fast and guaranteed to return the first number:

```
select top 1 (num + 1)
from tbl t
where not exists (select 1 from tbl t2 where t2.num = t.num + 1)
order by num;
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is another approach using `ROW_NUMBER`:

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9bd5b4/1/0)

```
;WITH CteRN AS(
    SELECT *,
        RN = num - ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY num)
    FROM tbl
)
SELECT TOP 1 num - RN
FROM CteRN
WHERE RN > 0
ORDER BY num ASC
```

---

With a proper `INDEX` on `num`, here is the stats under a million row test harness.

```
Original - NOT IN     : CPU time = 296 ms,  elapsed time = 289 ms
wewesthemenace        : CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms
notulysses(NOT EXISTS): CPU time = 687 ms,  elapsed time = 679 ms.
```

Comment: It scans the table only once.

Answer (score 2):

All the above answers are accurate alternatively if we can  make an table like date dimension that has all sequential number starting from 1 to n.

```
insert into sequenceNumber 
select 1 union all 
select 2 union all 
select 3 union all 
select 4 union all 
select 5 union all 
select 6 union all 
select 7 union all 
select 8 union all 
select 9 union all 
select 10 union all 
select 11 union all 
select 12 union all 
select 13


select * from sequenceNumber
```

RESULT:

1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13

Now we can use below query to find out missing number.

```
select a.num,b.num 
from sequenceNumber a
left outer join tbl b on a.num = b.num
where b.num is null
```

Hope it will be useful.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with `not exists`:

```
select top 1 t.num + 1
from tbl t
where not exists (select * from tbl where num = t.num + 1) order by t.num
```

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1e8fb3/3)

Or use a `row_number`:

```
select top 1 t.r
from (
   select num
        , row_number() over (order by num) as r
   from tbl) t
where t.r <> t.num
order by t.num
```

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1e8fb3/5)

Comment: This is quite slow for 10 million records

Answer (score 0):

from my side also one example

```
-- test data
DECLARE @Sequence AS TABLE ( Num INT )
INSERT  INTO @Sequence
        ( Num )
VALUES  ( 1 ),
        ( 2 ),
        ( 4 ),
        ( 5 ),
        ( 6 ),
        ( 8 ),
        ( 9 ),
        ( 11 ) 

--Final query
SELECT TOP 1
        S.RN AS [Missing]
FROM    ( SELECT    RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY num )
          FROM      @Sequence
        ) AS S
        LEFT JOIN @Sequence AS S2 ON S.RN = S2.Num
WHERE   S2.Num IS NULL
ORDER BY S.RN
```